# CollapsingToolbar inside a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-toolbar

I have been trying to put a Collapsing Toolbar inside a fragment I am using. The point is I am getting two Toolbars: one for the MainActivity as well as another for the specific fragment. I can't even avoid the MainActivity Toolbar as navigation drawer is also there. One more thing is When the specific Fragment appears on the screen and even the page doesn't cover the full screen after the Toolbar is collapsed. SO please help me in putting a Collapsing Toolbar inside a Fragment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once the toolbar set for current activity you can't change it. I mean if you call setSupportActionBar() multiple times, only first one will be successfull.

So you can't change Toolbar instance from fragment, but you can set it from there for first time. So you have two options:

1. Add some container to activity's AppBarLayout and then inflate needed content from fragment there.
2. Don't use a toolbat in activity and don't use setSupportActionBar at all. Just include toolbar to fragment and use some style (for activity) without ActionBar. It means you can fully control layout in fragment.

Comment: @evgenii- thank you for the reply. But inside the fragment also i need to show the NavigationDrawer that is placed in the MainActivity ActionBar and i need to show the NavigationDrawer all the time throughout the app. What to  do about it?

Comment: @AnimeshJena then you need to use first option with some container inside of AppBarLayout.